# Best strategy for committing and optimizing documents in Lucenet.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lucene.net

I'm facing some doubts about what is better related to performance and best practices.

My system will do:

1. Per document insert and update, or
2. Batch document insert

As I figured out (in previous systems) #2 is straight forward:

- Bulk delete old docs and add new ones, 10k docs max with no more then 20 fields per doc
- Commit
- Optimize

But the #1 still puzzles me as some customers will add docs one by one.

What is the penalty in commit and optimize at every insert and update? Or can I just ignore it as it only happens 20 times per day?

Java version is 3.5, .net version is 3.03

I just saw [a blog post](http://blog.trifork.com/2011/11/21/simon-says-optimize-is-bad-for-you/) and want to know about what community have to say about.

Comment: What are your requirements for how soon updated documents appear in your search results? That will tell us how often we want to commit. And yes optimize is mostly unnecessary at this point.

Comment: Is your index?  Is your index in memory?  Optimizing every 20 docs is overkill...if you really want to optimize it at 2am or some off hour.

Comment: The index need to be persisted if server goes down or the app crash for any reason so it will stay at file system. The index will serve the document search. The problem is it will be hosted mostly on shared hosts so I have no access schedule a routine or script to optimize on time basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no need to .Optimize() at all. Lucene will handle segment merges automatically, and you can provide your own logic to change how the merges are calculated. You could write something that merged away deleted documents when 10% of your documents are marked for deletion. There's no need for the functionality of Lucene to merge away every single deleted document.

Sure, you'll end up with more segment files and they will consume file descriptors, but have you ever ran into problems where you had too many files open? I tried googling for the maximum number of open files on a Windows server installation, but the answers varies from several thousand to limited by available memory.